# Can I move a partition on a virtual disk to physical disk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

When installing Windows 7 64-bit three years ago on my new build, I had to use a software tool ([Seagate DiskWizard](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/218619en)) to create a 'virtual' hard drive as I was using a 3TB drive (over the 2TB supported by Windows). I created a 2TB main partition on one of these 'disks' and a 500GB one on the other for media. This partition is now filled with 450GB of data. Recently I had a look on Disk Manager and discovered that the full 3TB is available on one disk, and on that physical disk there is 700GB of un-allocated space (which is actually being used by the 'virtual disk').

Here's an image of this
[image]

Now I would like to move the 'virtual' disk's partition onto the real hard drive to avoid any confusion, enable me to make even bigger partitions, and prevent loss of data by accidentally making a new partition and overwriting the 'virtual one'. Is there a way of:

1. Moving the partition from the virtual had drive to the physical one?
2. Deleting the virtual hard drive after transferring the partion.

Comment: Is it just a file disc that has nothing OS\Driver related installed?

Comment: I would just move your data to C: and delete your virtual disc and create a new extended partition on disk1 after which you can move your files there. (B.T.W. do you have an extra backup of your photo's? This is often forgotten and with a crash you'll loose everything)